# How can I make this LinqToSQL query work? (SqlExecption)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

The following code gives me an SqlException: *Invalid object name 'dbo.studentsCourses'*

```
OO theCourse = subject.Course;
var students = dc.studentsCourses.Where(x => x.course == theCourse).Select(x => x.student);
```

I tried the following code instead but I also get an Exception.
My original question was asked on Aardvark and can be read bellow:

```
var allStudents = from s in dc.students select s;
List thestudents = new List();
foreach (student s in allStudents)
{
     if (s.courses.Contains(theCourse))
     {
     thestudents.Add(s);
     }
}
```

I did a right click, "run custom tool" on my dbml and checked my names of my tables and entities. The project compiles but I get an Exception at runtime on this line:
"if (s.courses.Contains(theCourse))"
Any ideas?

**Original question on Aardvark:**

> How do I do a LinqToSQL query that
>   gives me this: I want to select all
>   students that attended a certain
>   lesson. The lesson is from a certain
>   course. So select the course the
>   lesson is from. Now select all the
>   students that are following that
>   course. There is a many-to-many
>   relationship between the students and
>   the courses table in my DB. I already
>   extended my LINQ entities to be able
>   to select student.Courses and
>   course.Students using this method:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq-to-sql-many-to-many.aspx

Comment: What does the SqlException say?

Comment: "Invalid object name 'dbo.studentsCourses'."

At the moment I am not looking at this problem anymore because I solved it using a workaround.

Off topic:
How can I mark this question as "solved" and how can I link to a reply to an answer, not the answer itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your link to sql classes don't match your db schema or your db does not contain a table or view called `studentcourses`. You need to adjust either your classes or db so they match.

Comment: I decided to CTRL-F replace all studentcourses wit student_courses (the table name) everywhere.
I don't understand how this fixed it but it's OK now.

Comment: Btw, the name should exist as an LinqToSQL entity, not necessarily as a table in your database, no?

Comment: The error was being caused by the fact that LinqtoSQL was generating SQL code that referenced a none existant database object, in this case a table.  This must have been cause by the fact that you had a class mapped to a none existant table, probably because the name of the database table had changed at some point.  Your LinqToSQL entities do not have to be named the same is their coresponding database tables, but they cannot be mapped to database tables that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could start debugging this problem by visualizing the query that is generated by the LinqToSQL. The Gu has written a blogpost on this a while ago:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx

Just copy/paste the query in your favourite database management application and run it against the database. It should become clear what the error is. If there are still some crazy things happening, just update your question?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First check your database to see if there is really a table or view name studentsCourses.
If there is then try to regenerate to dbml file and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure... but you may try this one:

var xxx = dc.Include("studentsCourses")
.studentsCourses
.Where(x => x.course == theCourse)
.Select(x => x.student)
.ToList();